# Angular js controller doesn't send data to mvc controller

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send data from angular js controller to mvc controller,the console throws out following error
POST:https://localhost:44321/DashBoard/GetVoucher 500

My C# Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult GetVoucher(Person model)
        {
            return Json("");
        }
```

My angular js post req:

```
try {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                data: $scope.data,
                url: '/DashBoard/GetVoucher',
                timeout: httpTimeout,
            }).then(function successCallback(response)
            {
                alert("in");
               
                },             
             function errorCallback(response) {

                console.log(response);

            });

        } catch (ex) { alert(ex); }
        }
```

with the error code 500 as mentioned above,console.log throws out following response:

```
<span>
        <H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

        <h2> <i>An item with the same key has already been added.</i> </h2>
    </span>

    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

        <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

        <br><br>

        <b> Exception Details: </b>System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.<br><br>

        <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

        <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <code>

                        An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
                    </code>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <br>

        <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

        <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <code>
                        <pre>

[ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) +56
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) +12948692
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.EntryLimitedDictionary.Add(String key, Object value) +54
   System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.AddToBackingStore(EntryLimitedDictionary backingStore, String prefix, Object value) +361
   System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.AddToBackingStore(EntryLimitedDictionary backingStore, String prefix, Object value) +146
   System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +69
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider() +30
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +105
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass3_1.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +640
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +346
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;BeginExecuteCore&gt;b__152_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +494
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;BeginExecute&gt;b__151_1(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +403
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__20_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +427
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +105
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +163
</pre>
                    </code>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <br>

        <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

        <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4250.0

    </font>
```

.Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check your `EventViewer` for errors. Check your VS debugger and bring more information. There are a million reasons for http code 500 and we can't figure it out without more information. Also in your error callback `alert(response);`

Comment: Question updated

Comment: can you show us the value of $scope.data ? The error message says that you have 2 properties in your model that your declared twice.

Comment: Thanks for your time,As you said i have missed a value .Now its working.